# How can I verify a package installer when there is no public key

Tags: gnupg, privoxy

I am preparing to install [privoxy](http://www.privoxy.org) and I expected to find the privoxy public key somewhere on their website or on SourceForge or on a keyserver. I can't find it. All gpg tutorials I have found suggest this is the important component of verifying a file is genuine.

I have [downloaded](http://www.privoxy.org/sf-download-mirror/Macintosh%20%28OS%20X%29/3.0.34%20%28stable%29/) the package installer and the accompanying `.asc` file but apparently without the developer's public key I can't verify it.

`Privoxy 3.0.34 64 bit.pkg.asc` 
`Privoxy 3.0.34 64 bit.pkg`

```
gpg --verify /Users/john/Downloads/Privoxy\ 3.0.34\ 64\ bit.pkg.asc /Users/john/Downloads/Privoxy\ 3.0.34\ 64\ bit.pkg 
gpg: Signature made Sun Feb  5 14:27:04 2023 CST
gpg:                using RSA key A90A85C1159F009DC3CDAE76451009FAB9D8A252
gpg: Can't check signature: No public key

gpg --keyserver https://pgp.mit.edu/ --search-keys A90A85C1159F009DC3CDAE76451009FAB9D8A252
gpg: data source: https://pgp.mit.edu:443
gpg: key "A90A85C1159F009DC3CDAE76451009FAB9D8A252" not found on keyserver
gpg: keyserver search failed: Not found
```

I am assuming I am at fault here. Why would a developer go to the trouble of posting the `.asc` file for the package if there wasn't a method to use it to verify the package?

Looking at [this old post](https://sourceforge.net/p/ijbswa/feature-requests/527/) it suggests that the public key should be available and are more useful than a hash.

I would appreciate any info/advice/help on this.

Thanks

## Additional action tried

```
gpg --import Privoxy\ 3.0.34\ 64\ bit.pkg.asc                       
gpg: no valid OpenPGP data found.
gpg: Total number processed: 0
```

Comment: The .asc file may contain the public key as well, so is it valid? Does `gpg2 --import file.pkg.asc` work, and/or does the file contain `-----BEGIN PGP PUBLIC KEY BLOCK-----`? I can't download it myself, but you're right that it's on them to provide the key

Comment: @Cpt.Whale `gpg: no valid OpenPGP data found`

Comment: @John - Update your question with that vital information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There doesn't seem to be any public key available.

From [Privoxy - Home Page](https://www.privoxy.org/) :

> Note that the Privoxy project currently has **no trusted build infrastructure**. Binary packages are built and uploaded by individual members of the Privoxy project or external contributors. For details check the signatures.

There is also no such key to be found in the
[download page](https://www.privoxy.org/sf-download-mirror/).

Comment: Thank you... I missed that. What do you suspect the purpose is of them recently adding an `.asc` file?

Comment: The package apparently was signed by the packager, but he has not published his public key to the keyservers and so one cannot verify that he is the package author. This happened already in [2017](https://lists.privoxy.org/pipermail/privoxy-users/2017-January/000158.html) when the answering developer had gotten in touch with the packager to remind of that. You can do the same today on the Privoxy mailing lists. To my thinking, downloading from a safe website is 99% sure.